# Is there any way to implement auto complete intellisense in fast colored textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

Is there any way implement intellisense in fastcolored textbox in vb.net

Comment: Intellisense, that's for code. Is that what is going in your textbox?

Comment: I faced a lot of design issues with **FastColoredTextbox** in the past, I really suggest you to migrate to **Scintilla.Net,** where you can implement code autocompletion/suggestions with examples in their wiki (if you will mean that, because Intellisense is just the name of that kind of implementations from Microsoft and only for visual Studio/VS-Code).